# What does the spacetime diagram for accelerated/non inertial observers look like?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, acceleration, relativity, inertial-frames

Suppose that we are in flat Minkowski spacetime. There are many inertial observers moving at constant speeds relative to eachother and a single non-inertial observer moving with constant acceleration. In all of the inertial frames, the spacetime diagram looks like this: one world-line coincides with the time axis, many straight world-lines represent the many inertial observers moving at constant speed and one curved world-line representing the accelerating observer. We can perform Lorentz transformations to build the spacetime diagram of another inertial observers and in all of them there will be many straight world-lines and the one curved world-line. However, what does the spacetime diagram of the accelerated observer look like? How can that transformation be performed? Is there any good simulation/image of what such transformation and spacetime diagram would look like?

Comment: See [Rindler coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Penrose Carter diagram for flat Minkowski spacetime looks like:

> The Penrose-Carter diagram of the flat Minkowski spacetime f
>   or an inertial observer looks like a diamond, in which
>   coordinate lines connect opposite apexes which are the spac
>   elike and timelike infinities. Borders of this diamond are
>   the lightlike infinities where world lines of light rays end.
>   The proper spacetime of an uniformly accelerated observer
>   is a small diamond included in the first one with one common spa
>   celike infinity. At first sight, the coordinate lines
>   for such an observer seems similar to those for the whole spac
>   etime (compare figure 1 with figure 4) but there are big
>   differences:
>
> •The time coordinate lines for the uniformly accelerated obs
>   erver end on the lightlike infinities of the whole
>   spacetime, while position coordinate lines end on one extre
>   mity at a spacelike infinity and on the other extremity,
>   due to the horizons, at a finite position.
>
> •Considered as functions of
>   ξ
>   or
>   ψ
>   , the slope at extremities of the coordinate lines for the uni
>   formly accelerated
>   observer varies from
>   −
>   1 to 1, while the slope at extremities is vanishing for the coo
>   rdinate lines of the inertial
>   observer.
>
> •There is not a perfect symmetry between time and position coo
>   rdinate lines for the uniformly accelerated
>   observer as it is the case for the coordinate lines of the iner

Please see the citation from here:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0611033.pdf